# unresolved external symbol _DbgPrint in Win7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, driver

I use VS2010 write my driver in Win7 64bit. The driver is simple and print something, like this:

```
#include <ntddk.h>

VOID 
OnUnload( IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject )
{
    DbgPrint("My Driver Unloaded!");
}

NTSTATUS 
DriverEntry( IN PDRIVER_OBJECT theDriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING theRegistryPath )
{
    NTSTATUS status;

    DbgPrint("My Driver Loaded!");
    theDriverObject->DriverUnload = OnUnload;

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I comple it, the VS2010 say: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _DbgPrint. I do not know why. The driver program in Win7 32bit is OK.

I think it may Lib config wrong, and I Lib config is:

```
C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\win7\ia64;
```

and include config is:

```
C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk;
C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\api;
C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc;
```

Is the config OK? What is place that I should notice? How do I fix it?

Comment: I set "C\C++ - Preprocessor - Preprocessor Definitions" item like this: WIN32=100;_X86_=1;WINVER=0x501;DBG=1. I think this is a problom, but I do not know how correct it

Comment: `C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\win7\amd64` ia64 for itanium, amd64 for x64

Comment: thank sergmat. You are right. It should be amd64. But I get "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _DbgPrint", again.

Answer (score 1):

VS 2010 is not used to compile and build drivers. However, Visual studio 2012 has this capability.

Prior to VS 2012, you need to use WinDDK to build drivers (I'm not sure if you can download it now).

Comment: I already install WinDDK, you can see I set lib "C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\win7\ia64;". and when I use WinDDk 's command to compile the program, this is no any error. So I think my project's config is wrong

Comment: @wenz, WinDDk compiler/mechanism is used to compile drivers. VS2010 will not work, as it would try to link/find user space runtime libraries.

Comment: I have used VS2010 to write and compile driver in WinXP and Win7(32bit). It is no problom. VS2010 can work if your config is right.